# Multiple updates queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

couldn't find information about this, hope it's not a repeated question.

I would like to update multiple documents in MongoDB, but using specific queries and update values for each one, for instance, I have this model:

user: {
 name: String,
 email: String
}

Lets say that I have 2 documents:

```
User_A: {
 name: 'Charles Montoya',
 email: 'charles@email.com'
}
User_B: {
 name: 'Robbin Faz',
 email: 'robbin@email.com'
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is something like this:

```
db.user.update([
{ name: 'Robbin Faz' }, { $set: { email: 'robbin@email2.com' }, { upsert: true } },
{ name: 'Charles Montoya' }, { $set: { email: 'charles@email2.com' }, { upsert: true} }
])
```

If something like this is not possible, which way do you recommend me to work with a list of updates?, or should I do a "for"?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a bulk update and or upset:

```
> var bulk = db.user.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
> bulk.find( { name: 'Robbin Faz' } ).upsert().update( { $set: { email: 'robbin@email2.com' } });
> bulk.find( { name: 'Charles Montoya' } ).upsert().update(  { $set:{ email: 'charles@email2.com' } });
> bulk.execute();
```